# HTMLImageElement.complete not returning correct value

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom

The code below works fine when page is loaded for the first time, it prints true/false if an img is loaded/not loaded.

But when I refresh the page, it prints false for all the imgs.

Why is this happening when the mdn docs says:

The image is considered completely loaded if any of the following are true:

1. The image element has previously determined that the image is fully available and ready for use.

[mdn doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/complete)

```
    let imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img");

    for(let img of imgs) {
      console.log(img.complete);
    }
```

Comment: when are you calling this code?

Comment: @DanielA.White, actually the the code above is a stripped down version. In my original code there is a `while` loop inside the `for` loop with the condition `!img.complete`.  When I reload the page the while loop condition never turns false.